# How can I capture shift-command-3/4 in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I seem to be able to capture the shift-command keyboard event and the press of '4'. However I can't get them both to stop the user from screen printing. Any pointers would be welcome.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Even if you figure out how to intercept this keypress that can't prevent someone from capturing the screen via other mechanisms.

Comment: This is a requirement for an exam application for one of our clients.

Comment: Thanks. It appears to be a dup. The original question was not actually answered and is over 2 years old, so I'm hoping for some fresh ideas.

Comment: Short answer: you can't.